# How to reconcile shared applabel in two third party apps in django?

Tags: django, wagtail, django-wiki

I have a large django project I am working on, that is largely based around the wagtail CMS. I recently added the django-wiki app to my project, and ran into issues running makemigrations, getting the error: "Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: sites
"

It seems both wagtail and django-wiki have apps and applables called 'sites', which is causing a conflict.

Given that these apps are not my apps, renaming them as though they were would seem like a bad approach, causing issues whenever I were to upgrade. What is the correct approach to deal with this problem without breaking the packages?

edit: My INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'home',

'django.contrib.sites.apps.SitesConfig',
'django.contrib.humanize.apps.HumanizeConfig',
'django_nyt.apps.DjangoNytConfig',
'mptt',
'sekizai',
'sorl.thumbnail',
'wiki.apps.WikiConfig',
'wiki.plugins.attachments.apps.AttachmentsConfig',
'wiki.plugins.notifications.apps.NotificationsConfig',
'wiki.plugins.images.apps.ImagesConfig',
'wiki.plugins.macros.apps.MacrosConfig',
    
"wagtail.contrib.routable_page",

'wagtail.contrib.forms',
'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
'wagtail.embeds',
'wagtail.sites',
'wagtail.users',
'wagtail.snippets',
'wagtail.documents',
'wagtail.images',
'wagtail.search',
'wagtail.admin',
'wagtail.core',

'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

Comment: Can you show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? What version of wagtail are you using? I believe the `sites` apps shouldn't have clashed.

Comment: I am using 2.13. I've added my installed apps to the question.

Comment: That's weird, you shouldn't be having that problem as wagtail sets the app label for `wagtail.sites` as `wagtailsites`.

Comment: Any tips on how I can further troubleshoot? I'm going to dig in and see if I can find where the app label is defined, it might give some hints.

Comment: Instead of `'wagtail.sites'` see if writing `'wagtail.sites.apps.WagtailSitesAppConfig'` makes a difference. Also what version of Django do you use?

Comment: I'm using Django 3.2.3, and unfortunately that change you suggested made no difference. Could it be a bug in django-wiki?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234737/discussion-between-abdul-aziz-barkat-and-jake-rankin).